# MySQL: How to avoid a situation requiring orphan rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm currently building a system where users have the ability to mark content they create as being either public or private. I would like to restrict some users to creating only public content or only private content, and allow others to choose.

To avoid using ENUM as a data type, I have a *types* table with two rows: "public" and "private". I also have an *allowed* table that takes a *userid* and a *typeid*. For example:

```
table: users; columns: id, username
table: types; columns: id, name
table: allowed; columns: userid, typeid
```

And I may have the following records in those tables:

```
users: [ 1, me ]
types: [ 1, public ], [ 2, private ]
allowed: [ 1, 2 ]
```

So the "me" user is only capable of creating private content.

This is all fine and well, because then I can use a foreign key in the *content* table to restrict their content settings.

```
table: content; columns: id, userid, typeid, content
[ content.userid, content.typeid ] references [ allowed.userid, allowed.typeid ]

content: [ 1, 1, 2, "some text" ]
```

But now, a year later, I have decided that "me" is now only capable of creating public content. So, I can delete the row from the *allowed* table for the "me" user and create a new one:

```
delete from allowed: [ 1, 2 ]
insert into allowed: [ 1, 1 ]
```

Problem is, I would love to ensure that **private content that they've already created stays private**, while only *new* content must be created as public. As far as I can tell from my research, this is simply a concept called *orphan rows*, which sounds exactly like the type of feature this design requires, but MySQL does not allow orphan rows at all.

What is the best way to maintain the integrity of the data? Conceptually, keeping the foreign key and allowing orphan rows is the perfect design. I could just do an if statement in PHP, but I'd like to find the "purist" solution, if there is one.

What would you recommend is an appropriate way to design this database?

Comment: What about triggers? Not "purist" enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` should reference the `users` and `types` tables, not the `allowed`  table. Foreign key constraints are mainly intended to maintain data integrity, not enforce security/permissions.

*As a side note, I would've just had two flags in the users table `can_create_public` and `can_create_private`; unless you were planning on creating new `types` (..."semi-public"?) having a table for it was probably overkill. In this scenario, `content` would just have a `private` flag.*

*I can see scenarios where you could want an expanding list of "types" but that would be more a much more complicated scenario of user group access rights, where the "groups" would be the types.*

Comment: I had considered that, but I wanted to leave the types open for expansion. Originally, I had thought about having "protected" as another type, but later decided that I didn't want to. But, if the ability to expand is there, I could add it later.

I get your point about integrity vs. authorization, though. I suppose an if statement is the appropriate way to go. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the issue.  You have a `typeid` column in the `content` table.  It is not going to change just because you change the `users` table -- unless you have a trigger that enforces something not described in the question.

Rather than deleting the record, however, I would suggest a type-2 dimension.  Basically, this has an `eff_date` and `end_date` which describe the period when the user/type combination is valid.  This would separate `typeid` from the `users` table, putting it instead in a `UserTypes` table.  This table would be "tiled" over time with the different types at different points in time.